# SSJS onClick action will not fire on XPage

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs, xpages-extlib

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17067991/xpages-button-on-page-will-not-fire), but it does not appear to be resolved, and I also have more to add.

First off, the linked question defines pretty much the same issue that I am having.
1. I am using the application layout control from the ExtLib
2. It does not matter if the button is in that control or not.
3. CSJS actions will fire from the button, SSJS actions will not fire.
4. No errors are present
5. Browser / cache is irrelevant as the server side action just will not fire.

After seeing the linked question, I looked in the Local file in the package view and found an anomaly that makes me wonder if it could be the cause.  I have never seen such a file before and even looked in my other xpage projects just to be sure.

[image: anomaly in local file]

This file cannot be deleted, and when clicked upon, the display window says that the element does not exist.

Does anyone know what this file is, how I can remove it, or could it be that my application is corrupted?

**More Info **

The following snippet is copied from the java file for the XPage located in the Local directory.  Everything looks fine to me.

```
private UIComponent createEventHandler(FacesContext context, 
                UIComponent parent, PageExpressionEvaluator evaluator) {
            XspEventHandler result = new XspEventHandler();
            String sourceId = "button2/xp:eventHandler[1]/xp:this.action[1]/text()";
            MethodBinding action = evaluator.createMethodBinding(result,
                    "#{javascript:view.postScript(\"alert(\'server script fired!\')\");}",
                    null,null, sourceId);
            result.setAction(action);
            result.setSubmit(true);
            result.setEvent("onclick");
            result.setRefreshMode("complete");
            return result;
        }
```

**EDIT**
Moving all of the design elements into a new .nsf so that file is no longer present does not change the problem of the SSJS onclick action not firing.  That strange file is however not present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it failing on a converter / validator? That can cause it to skip out of the lifecycle before Invoke Application phase. To test whether a button is actually working, you can also use "Do not validate or update data". Then the SSJS runs in Apply Request Values phase. If the SSJS is triggered (you won't have the latest data from the browser in the data model or components though), then it's another good bet for converter or validator failure.

Comment: The issue was being caused by a validator and not being able to pass the correct data type to the underlying setter in the data bean.  Changing the field type to a dojo number edit box, and then setting the javatype property under data in the all property tab to int corrected the issue.  This exception was only visible once a "show errors" control was added to the page.  Lesson learned, always include one!